# Quite the Namesake

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, story

> Me and a friend of mine named O were once trapped in a room with a
> shapeshifter (long story). I had a gun (even longer story), which was
> good because me and O needed to kill the shapeshifter (possibly the
> longest story?)
>
> Unfortunately for us, the shapeshifter had transformed into the
> perfect likeness of O, and I had no idea who was who!
>
> However, fortunately for us, me and O had prepared for a situation
> like this.
>
> Beforehand, me and O had created a special signal between only the
> both of us. Since the shapeshifter didn't know what the signal was, I
> would be able to tell the difference between the shapeshifter and O
> when I asked him for the signal (or him me, if the situation were
> reversed.)
>
> Confident that this system would work, I turned to the first O and
> asked for the signal. He performed it without hesitation: a small tap
> on his left bicep. However, when I levelled my gun at the second O, he
> told me not to shoot, that it was actually him, blah blah blah. I
> wasn't buying any of it.
>
> That is, until he offered to show me proof. I hesitated for a moment
> to allow him to try, not expecting him to be able to prove anything.
> However, he was: He also preformed the signal by tapping his lower
> bicep.
>
> Now I was very confused. My foolproof plan had been fooled! Ignoring
> both of the O's accusations of each other, I settled down for a moment to
> figure this problem out.

Which one should I shoot?

P.S. For the record, this puzzle is solvable, and I do already have an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should shoot

> the second O. When you asked the first O (the real O) for the signal, the second O (the shapeshifter) watched him do it. Then he offered to do it for you and did. I don't think any information is missing.

Comment: I accidentally said the missing info in the puzzle. Oops!